# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions How to dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs, observable

My goal is dispatch one action after another. First the actionOne should be dispatched and next the actionTwo should be dispatched. I am very new to redux.

action.js

```
export const actionOne = (value) => ({
    type: Explore.ACTION_ONE,
    payload: { value },
});
export const actioneTwo = payload => ({
    type: Explore.ACTION_TWO,
    payload,
});
```

reducer.js

```
case Explore.ACTION_ONE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tabs: somefunction(state),
                checkFlag: true
            };
        }
case Explore.ACTION_TWO: {
            return {
                ...state,
                checkFlag: false
            };
        }
```

There is another container(in its epic.js) where I call the above action

```
export const getCountEpic = (action$, store) =>
    action$.ofType(Constants.GET__COUNT).mergeMap(action => {
                return getCount(action.payload) // This returns our Observable wrapping the Promise
                .map(response => { //some code
           return [actionOne(updatedPayload),actionTwo(updatedPayload)];
             })
          .catch(error => {
                    return [getCountRejected(error)];
                })
                .takeUntil(action$.ofType(AnnotationConstants.GET__COUNT_CANCELLED));
});
```

I am not able to dispatch actionwTwo and get error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions". what is correct way to dispatch after actionOne is finished?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are returning an observable array, when the epic wants an observable object (or when two actions returned, a sequence of observable object).

This might be the pattern you require [Process Manager dispatch multiple actions](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/62#issuecomment-230327106)

```js
export const getCountEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(Constants.GET__COUNT)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      return getCount(action.payload)
        .flatMap(response => { 
          //some code
          return Observable.concat(
            Observable.of(actionOne(updatedPayload)),
            Observable.of(actionTwo(updatedPayload))
          )
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return [getCountRejected(error)];
        })
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(AnnotationConstants.GET__COUNT_CANCELLED));
});
```

or you might get away with simpler

```js
export const getCountEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(Constants.GET__COUNT)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      return getCount(action.payload)
        .map(response => { 
          //some code
          return Observable.of(
            actionOne(updatedPayload),
            actionTwo(updatedPayload)
          )
        })
...
```